# Replace everything that is not a float in a column with -1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to convert all the values in a col that are not float (str, nan, etc) to some garbage value like -99 (I replace this later in my code). For example

```
1.23

!DIV0

5.55

<0 

10.2

nan
```

I'd like the output to be

```
1.23

-99

5.55

-99

10.2

-99
```

I tried using `df.col.apply(lambda x: x.replace ...`

but it is using the str function replace and not the pd function

I don't think I can use `applymap` because another col in my dataframe is strings and I need to keep it that way

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df['col_name'],errors='coerce').fillna(-99)` ? apply isn't required IMO

Comment: @anky_91 you'll end up with floats of -99.00 though... don't know if that's apart or not for Gingerhaze though... would make more sense to just leave 'em as NaNs or maybe even `float('-inf')` depending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can use [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) function from pandas and let the error not to be raised and using fillna fill the NaN with garbage value

```
In [70]:  df = pd.DataFrame({'A':["HH",1.23,"!@",7]})

In [71]:  pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce').fillna(-99)
Out[71]:
0   -99.00
1     1.23
2   -99.00
3     7.00
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`df.col.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else -99)`

This should return `-99` if the argument isn't a float, otherwise it will not touch it.